# How to query a SingleResult object in a ASP.NET based server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, azure, azure-mobile-services

How do I query a SingleResult object in a ASP.NET based server? Please help with the below code.

```
public class UserController : TableController<User> 
{
...

public Task DeleteUser(string id)
{
    SingleResult<User> user = Lookup(id);
    // I can drill down into user via the debugger and see the data
    // I'm looking for. But I don't know how to translate what I see 
    // in the debugger to a .Net call. 

    // This is what I see in the debugger:
    // new System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView 
    // <AlertMeService.DataObjects.User>(result.Queryable).Items[0].GroupNm 
    // which equals "fooGrp" 

    // The below call doesn't work
    // string GroupNm = user.GroupNm;

    // I need GroupNm from the object to send a group notification
    PostNotification(user.GroupNm, ...);
    return DeleteAsync(id);
}
...
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I simply want to get user.GroupNm from the SingleResult object that lookup returns. I'm not sure how to typecast it.

Comment: Have you followed the following suggestions to check this issue, any updates?

Comment: Bruce, the below suggestion by Dai worked. Thanks for following up. -Mike

Comment: Done. Thanks for the instructions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SingleResult` returns an `IQueryable`, so use the Linq `Single` or `SingleOrDefault` methods to execute the query and get the result.

`Single` will throw an exception if 0, 2 or more values are returned, and `SingleOrDefault` will allow either 0 or 1 value and will throw if 2 or more than values are returned. If you want multiple values then use `First`/`FirstOrDefault` or `Last`/`LastOrDefault`, or some other terminal Linq method, as appropriate

```
SingleResult<User> userQuery = Lookup(id);
User user = userQuery.SingleOrDefault();
if( user == null ) {

}
else {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I have checked the `SingleResult` class:

```
public sealed class SingleResult<T> : SingleResult
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Http.SingleResult`1 class.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   queryable:
    //     The System.Linq.IQueryable`1 containing zero or one entities.
    public SingleResult(IQueryable<T> queryable);

    //
    // Summary:
    //     The System.Linq.IQueryable`1 containing zero or one entities.
    public IQueryable<T> Queryable { get; }
}
```

Per my understanding, you could modify your `DeleteUser` method as follows:

```html
public Task DeleteUser(string id)
{
    SingleResult<User> result = Lookup(id);
    var user=result.Queryable.SingleOrDefault();
    if(user!=null)
    {
      //I need GroupNm from the object to send a group notification
      PostNotification(user.GroupNm, ...);
      return DeleteAsync(id);
    }
    return Task.FromException($"the specific user with userid:{id} is not found.");
}
```